# Call the Rest API on the VisualForce page load

Tags: apex, visualforce

How can I call the HTTP REST API and show the data at the page loading time? I developed the code which has button and that I need to hit each time to get the results, instead I want to have the that data at page loading time.

```
public class ApexRestController {
    public List<CaseDetail> caseList {get; set;}

    public static String getAccessToken(){
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        req.setEndpoint('https://ap5.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token');

        String CLIENT_ID = 'xx';
        String CLIENT_SECRET = 'xx';
        String USERNAME = 'xx';
        String PASSWORD = 'XX';

        req.setBody('grant_type=password' + '&client_id='+CLIENT_ID + 
            '&client_secret='+CLIENT_SECRET + '&username='+USERNAME + '&password='+PASSWORD);

        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
        return getAccessTokenValue(res.getBody());
    } 

     public static String getAccessTokenValue(String jsonInput){
         Map<String, Object> data = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonInput);
         return (String) data.get('access_token');
    }

    public PageReference getCaseDetailsById(){
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('https://ap5.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Cases/XXXXXXXX');
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+getAccessToken());

        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
        String json = res.getBody();

        CaseDetail ca = (CaseDetail) System.JSON.deserialize(json.replace('"type"','"type_Z"'), CaseDetail.class);
        caseList = new List<CaseDetail>();
        caseList.add(ca);
        System.debug('Case Details : '+caseList);
        return null;
    } 
}
```

**CaseDetailsVFPage:**

```
<apex:page controller="ApexRestController">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:commandButton reRender="table1" value="Get Case Details" action="{!getCaseDetailsById}"/>
        </apex:pageBlock>

        <apex:pageBlock id="table1">
            <b>Output Contact Details </b>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!caseList}" var="ca">
                <apex:column headerValue="Id" value="{!ca.Id}" />
                <apex:column headerValue="CaseNumber" value="{!ca.CaseNumber}" />
                <apex:column headerValue="Subject" value="{!ca.Subject}" />
                <apex:column headerValue="Status" value="{!ca.Status}" />
                <apex:column headerValue="Priority" value="{!ca.Priority}" />
                <apex:column headerValue="Type" value="{!ca.Attributes.type_Z}" />
                <apex:column headerValue="URL" value="{!ca.Attributes.url}" />
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: I can suggest you read https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_lifecycle.htm which describes Order of Execution in a Visualforce Page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your requirement you should use `apex:page` action as follows:

```
<apex:page controller="ApexRestController" action="{!getCaseDetailsById}">
</apex:page>
```

> The action method invoked when this page is requested by the server. Use expression language to reference an action method. For example, action="{!doAction}" references the doAction() method in the controller.
>   If an action isn’t specified, the page loads as usual. If the action method returns null, the page simply refreshes.
>
> This method is called before the page is rendered, and allows you to optionally redirect the user to another page.
>
> Important: This action should not be used for initialization or DML.

Comment: Such a great solution. Appreciated sir. !!